# How to get the ID of Whatsapp Template in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Is there any way to access the content of the Twilio Whatsapp template with PHP ? Something like accessing the template ID. In the detail of the template created the ID is not shown.My problem is that to send a Whatsapp  message I have to copy exactly the same text of the body, and I need it to be something more dynamic than that, because if a space or line is missing, the message is not sent.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Templates are meant to be static with variables that can change. WhatsApp doesn't allow dynamic templates.

However, there's a new Content Template Builder that allows you to build better Business-initiated or user-initiated templates for WhatsApp. After creating and submitting a template, a "Content template SID" will be generated. See the image below.

You can play around with content templates using [Twilio Postman collection](https://assets.cdn.prod.twilio.com/documents/Content_Template_Builder.postman_collection.json). You can read more about this in their docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/overview)

For the old templates, The ID is in the URL bar.

[image]